lean4: usage for sorry vs admit
admit in lean4 is described as a shorthand for exact sorry, but both sorry and admit are implemented in the same manner:
/--
The `sorry` tactic closes the goal using `sorryAx`. This is intended for stubbing out incomplete
parts of a proof while still having a syntactically correct proof skeleton. Lean will give
a warning whenever a proof uses `sorry`, so you aren't likely to miss it, but
you can double check if a theorem depends on `sorry` by using
`#print axioms my_thm` and looking for `sorryAx` in the axiom list.
-/
macro "sorry" : tactic => `(tactic| exact @sorryAx _ false)

/-- `admit` is a shorthand for `exact sorry`. -/
macro "admit" : tactic => `(tactic| exact @sorryAx _ false)

Is this some leftover deprecated macro from lean3, or is there a reason as to using admit in lean4?

As of four days ago with #5757,
the admit tactic is now a synonym for the sorry tactic and the docstring says "admit is a synonym for sorry," which is hopefully clearer.
I'll mention that the tactic is not exact @sorryAx _ false anymore. Instead, it's exact sorry, and the sorry term creates a sorryAx term that contains source position information, to support "go to definition" in any sorry that appears in the Infoview, and also an additional unique token to ensure that two sorrys created at different times will never be definitionally equal.

They are the exact same.  admit is just a synonym for sorry, probably since other proof assistants like Coq call it admit.
There is more discussion about it here, and an RFC to deprecate admit (but without much support from the Lean maintainers).  All things being equal, I would use sorry since it is canonical, idiomatic Lean, but it probably doesn’t make much difference.

Coq has admit and give_up I suppose for the same purpose: just convey a different programmer's intent.
